# Does anyone know the exact details of the first part of the Horse Sacrifice yagna?

Tags: vedas, ramayana, symbolism, yajna

I am trying to find out details of the pole and the corresponding circle type mandala in the Horse Sacrifice. Did the mandala, where the pole was placed, have orientation to the four cardinal directions? I am doing research for a book on the symbolism of four merging to one such as in the squaring of a circle. Susan